# How to prevent MSDeploy task from rebuilding assemblies?

Tags: iis, msbuild, teamcity, obfuscation, msdeploy

I am running an TeamCity Build Server that builds and deploys a asp.net 4.0 application.  I need to obfuscate the assemblies of prior to deployment.  I have two build configurations.  One is SVN triggered that compiles and packages.  Packaging is done through:
- Calling MSBuild with web project file as build file
- using the following parameters: /T:Package

The second configuration is manually triggered and only does deployment.  Again, it calls MSBuild and uses the following parameters:

> /P:Configuration=%env.Configuration% /P:DeployOnBuild=False /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://%env.TargetServer%/MsDeploy.axd /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /P:UserName=Administrator /P:Password=%env.DeployPassword%

As you can see, DeployOnBuild is set to false, as well as CreatePackageOnPublish.  Still, when I run this build configuration, the assemblies are rebuilt.

I would like have a step prior to deployment that obfuscates the assemblies.  And then have the deployment step simply deploy the obfuscated assemblies.  How do I need to call MSuild in order for it to skip the compile step and move immeditely to publish?

Another that is manually triggered and only does deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The `Package` target is defined in the `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` file. If you have a look in there you will see extensibility points.

This blog post on [Extending the MSBuild Package target](http://www.ronaldrosier.net/blog/2013/06/29/extending_the_msbuild_package_target) gives some examples.